# Javascript nested array single element modification transforms into whole array modification

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having issues with this code:

```
var openingSegments = Array(7).fill([]);
openingSegments[0].push({'start': '1100', 'end': '1900'});
```

Because when I do:

```
console.log(openingSegments);
```

It gives me :

```
[ [ { start: '1100', end: '1900' } ],
  [ { start: '1100', end: '1900' } ],
  [ { start: '1100', end: '1900' } ],
  [ { start: '1100', end: '1900' } ],
  [ { start: '1100', end: '1900' } ],
  [ { start: '1100', end: '1900' } ],
  [ { start: '1100', end: '1900' } ] ]
```

As if I had pushed all the elements of 'hoursOfDay' which is not the case since i only applied push on the very first element (index 0).

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill` just copies the passed argument across all items. Actually you have only one array object and `7` reference  copies of that object pushed into the array. Changing array via one reference affects all items.

Instead of `fill` you can use [**Array#from**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) function with the `mapFn` parameter of it.

```js
var openingSegments = Array.from({ length: 7 }, x => []);
openingSegments[0].push({'start': '1100', 'end': '1900'});

console.log(openingSegments[0]);
console.log(openingSegments[1]);
```

Comment: ok this is really much appreciated ! So now should I take down this answer because it wasn't the right question or ?

Answer (score 0):

Array.fill just fills your array with the exact same objects.

This is basically how fill works:

```
function fillFunc(size, element) {
  const resultArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    resultArray.push(element);
  }
  return resultArray;
}
const filledArray = fillFunc(7, []);
```

As you can see, the resulting array just gets filled with references to the initial object. I'd go with something other than Array.fill() for your particular needs.